# Зачем наследоваться от RegExp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения, frontend

Встречал в статьях о регулярках в JavaScript, упоминания о возможности наследовать свои классы от класса RegExp, т.е. делать что-то в духе:

class MyRegExp extends RegExp {};

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это даёт в практическом смысле, где это может пригодиться, что интересного можно написать?

Comment: можно паттерн свой какой-то сразу сделать, условно, `NumericExp`, или постобработку добавить какую-то. Если типовая задача есть некая, то это повод для создания класса и таскания его с собой. Если таких повторяемых задач нет, и вопроса повторного использования кода не появляется, то и говорить не о чем. В целом это касается любой задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну это по сути удобная версия взамен работы через прототипы. Раньше через прототипы расширялось

```
RegExp.prototype.customMethod = function() {
  console.log("Новый метод");
};

let pattern = /\d+/;
console.log(pattern.test("123456987"));  // "true"
pattern.customMethod();  // "Новый метод"
```

то в ES6 будет удобней и универсальнее

```
class CustomRegexpClass extends RegExp {
  customMethod() {
    console.log("Новый метод");
  }
}

let pattern = new CustomRegexpClass(/\d+/);
console.log(pattern.test("123456987"));  // "true"
pattern.customMethod();  // "Новый метод"
```